# proof verification on compact metric with $d(A,B)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B$ non empty subsets. If $A$ is compact show that $d(A,B)=0\Leftrightarrow A\cap \overline{B}\neq \varnothing  $

$$  d(A,B)=\inf\left \{ d(a,b):a\in A ,b\in B  \right \}$$

$\Rightarrow $

let's suppose  $A\cap \overline{B}= \varnothing  $ now because $A$ is compact and $\overline{B}$ is closed then it's been proved that $d(A,B)>0$ , contradiction

$\Leftarrow $

let $A\cap \overline{B}\neq \varnothing  $, I will prove that $d(A,B)=0$, because   $A\cap \overline{B}\neq \varnothing  $, I can take $(x_n)\subseteq A   $ and $z_n \in A\cap \overline{B}$ so $z_n\in B\left(x_n,\frac{1}{n}\right)$

$d(x_n,z_n)< \dfrac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$

$y_n\in B $ and $z_n\in B\left(y_n,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ we can approach $d(A,B)$ with a sequence $d(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow d(A,B)$ $d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,z_n)+ d(z_n,y_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

$d(A,B)=0 $

Is this ok?

Comment: *Where* it has been proved that, if $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, then $d(A,B)>0$?

Comment: The proof seems right but I think is a bit hard to read. Maybe in the right to left implication chose a point $a\in A\cap \overline{B}$ and take $y_n\in B$ such that $d(a,y_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$. Then $d(A,B)$ is less than the limit of those distances.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos_ its been proven in my class of course I forgot to mention it, this was not a good post, i was in a hurry. i apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good start.

$\Rightarrow$: as @José Carlos Santos has pointed out, there's a gap here. Hint: each point in $A$ has a neighborhood that's disjoint from $B$, which gives an open cover of $A$, so you can use compactness.

$\Leftarrow$: I don't understand where your $z_n$ are coming from. I suggest you start with a point $x \in A \cap \overline{B}$, and then a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$, and then the rest of your argument should work.